# Are there any ferries currently running on the Black Sea between Romania and Georgia?

Tags: romania, ferries, georgia-country, black-sea, eastern-europe

I plan to visit Romania and Georgia this year and would love to consider the possibility of travelling between them on the Black Sea. I know both countries have various ports and have or have previously had various ferries or other types of sea travel on the Black Sea.

But regular web searches return a lot of out-of-date information and I feel the current information may be concealed in a variety of uncommon languages.

So, is it possible in 2019 to travel from Romania To Batumi or Poti in Georgia on the Black Sea? If so, what companies, times, and prices?

Comment: hi this is an old thread...did you find a black sea ferry?

Comment: I ended up just hitchhiking across Turkey again. But I've met several people along the way asking about ferries so I think it's still a good question even though I didn't find my own answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://www.ferrylines.com/en/ferries/ferries-in-the-black-sea/

it would seem to be NO, but it does indicate you could travel to Bulgaria.

Aussies don't need a visa for Bulgaria, so you could then take a train up to Bucharest from within Bulgaria.  Bucharest to Istanbul is 16 hours, so from Bulgaria wouldn't be a long trip.

Comment: I have read a thread this morning on CouchSurfing which says there is a ferry from Odessa in the Ukraine to Poti in Georgia for not much more than $50 but I don't know if it stops anywhere else along the route.