# What is the price of ferries between Bulgaria and Georgia?

Tags: ferries, georgia-country, bulgaria, black-sea, batumi

[A previous question about Romania and Georgia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/292/are-there-any-ferries-currently-running-on-the-black-sea-between-romania-and-the) mentioned that there are ferry connections between Bulgaria and Georgia. Somebody I've met at my new hostel is interested in just a ferry so I dug up that old question to see.

However when I follow through the links I find one company is not running until they can replace one of their ships and the other links to http://www.navbul.com/ which doesn't seem to have any info on their routes let alone their prices and times. For me it only loads in English so I can't try a trick like translating their site from Bulgarian or Russian or anything that might have more information.

Or maybe there's some third party website that has details about navbul's connections?

Is anybody able to find anything I've missed? I don't mind which ports but would prefer to land in Batumi if there is an option.

Answer (score 7):

I think you just need to dig a bit deaper into the NavBul website!

From their [Ferry page](http://www.navbul.com/en/main-activities/ferry/):

> Two identical ferryboat vessels operated by NAVIBULGAR ("Geroite na Sevastopol" and "Geroite na Odesa") each with total carrying capacity of 108 waggons/900 cars/100 motor trucks up to 16m length operate the regular lines:
>
> Varna - Ilichevsk - Varna
>
> Varna - Ilichevsk - Poti/Batumi - Ilichevsk - Varna
>
> The trade name of Navibulgar's ferry line forwarding branch is FERRYSPED. It provides a "door to door" carriage of all types of cargo (railway rolling stock, trucks, and containers, passengers, deck cargo and cars) to and from Ukraine, Belarus, Kazakhstan, Uzbekistan, Georgia, Armenia, Azerbaijan, Iran, Afganistan, Turkey, Greece, Macedonia and Yugoslavia, using railway, maritime and auto transport.

Then the bit you probably want is their [schedule PDF](http://www.navbul.com/en/files/ferry-schedule.pdf) which lists the dates they're sailing for the next two months. I'd suggest you ring them / email them (details at the end of the schedule) and ask for the departure timings on the days you're considering going.

Comment: Ah so it looks like all ships take a long route north via Ukraine and not the direct route along the south of the Black Sea. Oh and no indication of prices. But thanks very much for what you did find!

Comment: The link to the schedule is broken right now ...

Answer (score 7):

May be it's too late, but here is the result of my research. I haven't found the price for the line Navbul mentioned by the op, but there is another company that connects Varna (Bulgaria) and Batumi/Poti (Georgia) ports: UKRFerry

The price for this route is from [120 USD per person](http://www.ukrferry.com/eng/tariffs/tariffs-pass-varna-batumi) (depending on the accomodation chosen) and [350 USD per car](http://www.ukrferry.com/eng/tariffs/tariffs-cargo-varna-batumi).

Comment: Thanks Ivan. It's never too late for answers on Stack Exchange. Answers are more for people that find the question by Googling than for the OP. Ideally they get updated as they age.

Answer (score 5):

Both of ships Gagravar have mentioned are from [UkrFerry](http://www.ukrferry.com/eng/shipping/schedule-ports.php) company. And yes, they are currently ships accross the Black Sea:

```
Poti    September 12, 2011  Ilyichevsk  September 15, 2011  "Geroi Sevastopolya"
Poti    September 12, 2011  Varna   September 21, 2011  "Geroi Sevastopolya"
Ilyichevsk  September 19, 2011  Varna   September 21, 2011  "Geroi Sevastopolya"
Ilyichevsk  September 19, 2011  Batumi  September 26, 2011  "Geroi Sevastopolya"
Varna   September 23, 2011  Batumi  September 26, 2011  "Geroi Sevastopolya"
```

And other ship:

```
Varna   September 15, 2011  Batumi  September 20, 2011  "Geroi Odessy"
Batumi  September 21, 2011  Varna   September 28, 2011  "Geroi Odessy"
Ilyichevsk  September 26, 2011  Varna   September 28, 2011  "Geroi Odessy"
Ilyichevsk  September 26, 2011  Batumi  October 03, 2011    "Geroi Odessy"
Varna   September 30, 2011  Batumi  October 03, 2011    "Geroi Odessy"
```

Comment: Any reasons to downvote?